# SAX vs DOM performance in XML, with real example?

Tags: c#, xml

What is the difference between SAX and DOM in xml?
Please give me an example.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: If you really want to understand this, read Elliotte Rusty Harold's book on Java and XML. You're not going to gain an understanding from explanations written here in 2 minutes, even if the author is an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this SAX description (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML).

This DOM description (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).

Use this C Sharp example (https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/682245/NanoXML-Simple-and-fast-XML-parser)

Answer (score 1):

The difference isn't in performance. The main difference is the DOM approach needs enough memory to store the whole document, while the SAX approach processes it piece by piece. For very large XML documents, it might even be impossible to use the DOM at all, while a SAX still works.